# Postgresql locks and copy_expert

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am copying data into few postgresql tables using cursor.copy_expert command. After loading the data , I see the mode set to "AccessShareLock" , "RowExclusiveLock", "ShareUpdateExclusiveLock" against these tables when I run the below query -

```
select t.relname,l.locktype,page,virtualtransaction,pid,mode,granted from pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t where l.relation=t.relid order by relation asc;
```

Are these tables locked by the copy_expert command and how are different tables associated with different locks?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of this problem, commit all the parameters tuning autovacuum and auto-analyze at relation level have been updated to use SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE LOCK. In short, this allows read as well as write operations to occur in parallel of the ALTER TABLE, something that will definitely help leveraging activity bloat on such relations.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
   SET (vacuum_truncate = on,
        toast.vacuum_truncate = on);

ALTER TABLE SET autovacuum storage options
```

Note as well that when multiple subcommands are used, the stronger lock of the whole set is taken for the duration of the ALTER TABLE command. So for example, should an update on the parameter fillfactor be mixed with a modification of autovacuum_enabled, an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock will be taken on the relation instead of a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock. ALTER TABLE uses the following set of locks, and those having a monotonic relationship it is possible to establish a hierarchy of them, the strongest one being the first listed here:

ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK

SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE LOCK

SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE LOCK

[sql vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-vacuum.html)